# How can i Perform Coverflow using 3D effect?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to Show images using cover flow effect.I have done with Normal coverflow but now i want to add some 3d effect in it so please any suggestion regarding this help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different CoverFlow, but I think [FlowCover](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html) is best to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project called Tapku Library, check out the TKCoverflowView class. Hope it helps.

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a free library for this that allows you to specify your own 3d transform for the CoverFlow effect, or choose from a selection of built-in styles: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel